# JRuby deployment into Tomcat - org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, jruby, rack

I got my app running and perfectly working in WeBRICK and Trinidad.

The thing is that now I need to make a deployment into Tomcat.

Im using Jruby and Rails 3, when I create the deployment it fails with the current message:

```
SEVERE: ERROR: unable to create shared application instance

org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: load error: /usr/local/webservices/tmp/0-SPARK/WEB-INF/config/environment -- java.lang.NullPointerException: null

    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1027:in `require'

    from /usr/local/webservices/tomcat-servers/tctqan04/work/Catalina/localhost/SPARK/loader/jruby/rack/rails/environment3.rb:23:in `load_environment'

    from /usr/local/webservices/tomcat-servers/tctqan04/work/Catalina/localhost/SPARK/loader/jruby/rack/rails_booter.rb:65:in `load_environment'

    from <script>:1:in `(root)'
```

Does any one have an idea of what the problem might be and how to solve it?

Regards.

Comment: Its not Tomcat but TorqueBox is whole JRuby/Rack platform. http://torquebox.org/

Comment: *How* are you creating the deployment? Warbler? Other?